# tabs changing issue on ui-select

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

In `ui-select`, user must tab multiple times to move out of ui-select input.

I don't know why it is happening, but on checking I found that it only happens when I select the drop down value through `tab`. If I select it through `click` or `enter`, then tab switches to next element smoothly.

Here's the html code:

```
<ui-select ng-model="noPostData.selectedtype.id" theme="select2" on-select="getUserOptions()">
      <ui-select-match placeholder="Select user type">{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
      <ui-select-choices repeat="obj.id as obj in usertype | filter: {name: $select.search} | limitTo: 200">
       <div ng-bind-html="obj.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
          </ui-select-choices>
     </ui-select>
```

Comment: Check this out. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/ui-select for your case set *close-on-select*  to false, reference https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/pull/1534 let me know it works or not!

Comment: nope. in docs it says, by default its true.